Convert an equation to its elliptic form
I am failing to convert
$L = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\phi_0} \frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{\sin \phi_0 - \sin \phi}} d\phi$
into
$L=\int_{\theta_1}^{\pi/2}\frac{2k^2\sin^2(\theta)-1 }{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}}d\theta$.
The original manuscript makes the following substitution
$1+\sin(\phi)=2k^2\sin^2(\theta)=(1+\sin\phi_0)\sin^2\theta$
Yet, something is amiss.
If you would be so kind as to lend a hand?
(Incidentally this is the solution to the problem of large deformation in a cantilevered beam)

$\sin(\pi/2-x)=\cos x$, $\cos2x=2\cos^2 x-1$


Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by the integral
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\beta\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\beta\right)}-\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}.$$

Personally, for me it always helps to put the elliptic integral into algebraic form before attempting to reduce it to standard form so as to make the substitutions less opaque.
Suppose $\beta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Set $b:=\sin{\left(\beta\right)}$, and note that $0<b<1\implies0<\frac{1+b}{2}<1$.
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\beta\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\beta\right)}-\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\sin{\left(\beta\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{\sin{\left(\beta\right)}-t}};~~~\small{\left[\varphi=\arcsin{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\sqrt{b-t}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t}{\sqrt{\left(1-t\right)\left(b-t\right)\left(t+1\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{b+1}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\left(b+1\right)\left[\left(b+1\right)u-1\right]}{\sqrt{\left[2-(b+1)u\right]\left(b+1\right)\left(1-u\right)\left(b+1\right)u}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{t+1}{b+1}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{b+1}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)u-1}{\sqrt{2u\left(1-u\right)\left[1-\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)u\right]}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left[1-\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)x^{2}\right]}};~~~\small{\left[u=x^{2}\right]}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2k^{2}x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-k^{2}x^{2}\right)}},\\
\end{align}$$
where in the last line above we've set
$$k:=\sqrt{\frac{1+b}{2}}\in(0,1),$$
$$\alpha:=\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b}}\right)}\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
A final substitution $x=\sin{\left(\theta\right)}$ will of course put the integral into the form you were seeking.
If you'd like to know more about the nuts and bolts of where the appropriate substitutions come from, I learned a great deal from this set of notes: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~glabahn/Papers/ellipticPrePrint.pdf


Let's rewrite each piece of
$$
L=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\phi_0} \frac{\sin\phi\,d\phi}{\sqrt{\sin \phi_0 - \sin \phi}} \tag{1}
$$
in terms of $\theta$ using the substitution given in the OP,
$$
1+\sin\phi=2k^2\sin^2\theta=(1+\sin\phi_0)\sin^2\theta. \tag{2}
$$
It follows immediately from $(2)$ that
$$ 
\sin\phi=2k^2\sin^2\theta-1. \tag{3} 
$$
Next, we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sin\phi_0-\sin\phi}&=\sqrt{(1+\sin\phi_0)-(1+\sin\phi)} \\
&=\sqrt{2k^2-2k^2\sin^2\theta} =\sqrt{2}k\cos\theta. \tag{4}
\end{align}
Differentiating both sides of the first equality in $(2)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\cos\phi\, d\phi=4k^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta \implies d\phi=\frac{4k^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\cos\phi}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Using $(3)$, we rewrite the denominator of $(5)$ as
\begin{align}
\cos\phi &= \sqrt{1-\sin^2\phi} = \sqrt{1-(2k^2\sin^2\theta-1)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{4k^2\sin^2\theta-4k^4\sin^4\theta} 
= 2k\sin\theta\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Plugging $(3)$-$(6)$ into $(1)$, we finally obtain
\begin{align}
L &=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}
\frac{(2k^2\sin^2\theta-1)\times 4k^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{2}k\cos\theta\times 2k\sin\theta\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} \\
&=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\frac{(2k^2\sin^2\theta-1)\,d\theta}
{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}, \tag{7}
\end{align}
where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the values of $\theta$ corresponding to $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\phi_0$, respectively. Using $(2)$, we find
$$
1=(1+\sin\phi_0)\sin^2\theta_1 \implies \theta_1
=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi_0}}\right), \tag{8}
$$
$$
1+\sin\phi_0=(1+\sin\phi_0)\sin^2\theta_2 \implies \theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{9}
$$

waw, chtGPT 4.0 nearly did it, but kept on hallucinating half way through. Very impressive
